# Change of variables on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

This might seem trivial but I am having some issues with the following problem.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bi-Lipschitz map, $\Omega$ a bounded Lipschitz domain. Assume $f$ is the identity on $\partial \Omega$ and that $g \in L^1(\partial \Omega)$ is given. Then, clearly, $\int_{\partial \Omega} g d\sigma_\Omega=\int _{\partial{f(\Omega)}}gd\sigma_{f(\Omega)}$, so that the latter integral doesn't depend on $f$.

Now, consider [this](https://membres-ljk.imag.fr/Charles.Dapogny/publis/optbc3.pdf) article. With additional smoothness assumptions, at page 9, just above (3.7), it is stated $\int _{\partial{f(\Omega)}}gd\sigma_{f(\Omega)} = \int_{\partial \Omega}|com(Jf)n_\Omega| g\circ fd\sigma_\Omega$. Here $n$ is the normal and $com(Df)=det(Df)Df^{-T}$. To me, the integral on the right hand side is not independent of $f$, because $Df$ need not to be the identity on $\partial \Omega$.

My questions are:

- how can I see the integral is constant w.r.t. $f$, if it is?
- do you have a reference for the formula above, in case of the smoothness hypothesis made in the beginning?

---

Edit: the characterization of $com$ is stated [here](https://www.math.uni-trier.de/%7Eschmidt/publications/thesis.pdf)  at page 23.